# MATLAB Lsim initial value for RC filter doesnt work

Tags: matlab, filtering, transfer-function

I would simulate an RC (low-pass) filter that has some initial value.
[image]

```
R = 1e3; % 1kOm
C = 100e-6; % 100uF
es = tf('s');
LP1 = 1 / (R*C*es + 1);
Ts = 0.1; % 100ms
sysd = c2d(LP1, Ts);
```

Initial value means that capacitor is charged to some voltage (lets say 5V) and we apply some voltage to the input (lets say 10V). I would see output voltage / time plot:

```
x0 = 5; % 5V
input = 10; % 10V
N = 100;
lsim(sysd, ones(1, N)*input, [], x0);
```

Plot that is showed starts with zero (no initial condition). If i convert tf to ss:

```
lsim(ss(sysd), ones(1, N)*input, [], x0);
```

Than plot starts from non zero value but it is NOT 5V that I set as initial value.
[image]
What is wrong with it, How to simulate it?

Answer (score 0):

The `x0` input to `lsim()` is only used to define the initial conditions of a state-space system.

- In the first example, `sysd` is a transfer function, so `x0` has no effect and a zero initial condition is used.
- In the second example, `ss(sysd)` is a state-space model, so `x0` specifies the initial **state** and not the output as you intended. To understand what is going on, let's take a look at your state-space model:

```
>> ss(sysd)

ans =

  A = 
           x1
   x1  0.3679

  B = 
       u1
   x1   1

  C = 
           x1
   y1  0.6321

  D = 
       u1
   y1   0

Sample time: 0.1 seconds
Discrete-time state-space model.
```

Per the [state-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-space_representation) output equation `y = Cx + Du` , the initial output is equal to `C*x0 = 0.6321*5 = 3.16` which matches the result in your plot. Instead, you should set `x0 = y0 / ss(sysd).C` where `y0` is the desired initial output. For `y0 = 5`, this means setting `x0 = 7.91`.